# Geometric meaning of boundary of $k$-simplex

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a $3$-simplex $\sigma = [0,p_{1},p_{2},p_{3}]$ where $p_{1}=(1,0,0),p_{2}=(0,1,0),p_{3}=(0,0,1)$. By definition of the boundary of $k$-simplex, $$\partial \sigma = [p_{1},p_{2},p_{3}]-[0,p_{2},p_{3}]+[0,p_{1},p_{3}]-[0,p_{1},p_{2}]$$
My question is, what is the geometric meaning of the boundary? Can someone visualize it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you draw the pyramid with vertices at $0,p_1,p_2,p_3$, the boundary consists of the facets; the triangles with vertices at each of the triples in the formula. They are put as a sum with signs representing orientation. The orientation is chosen to agree with the fundamental theorem of calculus, in which an interval $[a,b]$ gets replaced by (evaluation at) its end-points $b,a$, but (evaluation at) $a$ is used with the opposite sign ($F(b)-F(a)$).

Comment: More geometrically, the orientation is chosen to agree with the right hand rule, where the thumb of your right hand is pointing in the direction of the outward normal vector on each face.